# Problems with Asus Zenbook UX433F

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, sound, laptop, asus

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in dual boot on my Asus laptop [Zenbook UX433F](https://www.asus.com/us/Search/results.aspx?SearchKey=UX433F&IsSupport=True&Page=1) without success. In attempt #1 with 18.04.2, the audio didn't work and the laptop often crashed. Attempt #2 with 18.04.3, both "Install Ubuntu" and "Try Ubuntu" give me a black screen with no way to provide input.

I read many posts about issues with this laptop model. Can it be incompatible with Ubuntu at all?

Maybe the problem is the kernel version?

I tried with different USB devices and with LiveUSBs made with both Unetbootin and Rufus.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: @Sab Please try solutions outlined in the comment above, then come back here to report results. If something fails, please include error messages. Also, please checksum verify https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 the downloaded ISO files used to make the LiveUSB & advise you did. Specific laptops can have issues which may require changes in the BIOS /firmware settings, and/or may also require changes in the GRUB boot menu https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076

Comment: I resolved adding dis_ucode_ldr to my kernel command line (from GRUB), it's able to boot normally!